# How do you expand variables in UNIX/BASH?

Tags: bash, unix, variables

Nested variables have prevented me from trying to use BASH more extensively... consider the following:

```
export SYS_DIR='/home/${LOGNAME}/sys'
export APP_DIR='${SYS_DIR}/app'
```

I always end up with

```
> set
APP_DIR=/home/${LOGNAME}/sys/app
```

why? lol

and how do I get what I want =/

I'm not trying to resolve ${${var}}, but rather actual strings as shown above

Comment: Strings in single quotes are not expanded.

Comment: mwuaha I just noticed that! lol

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use double quotes

```
export APP_DIR="${SYS_DIR}/app"
```

Single quotes treat everything inside as literal, not evaluated.

Comment: Additionally, consider looking into "Advanced Bash Guide" via Google for all things bash ;)

Comment: But, alias evaluates though the variables are in single quotes. Why? E.g. `alias abc='cd ${HOME}'`